# Password confirmation with 2 UITextFields

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I want the user to confirm the password he typed it... so I use two text fields.. But somehow even if both have the same password it seems to think that the 2 strin  differ

```
   if (![self.typePTextField.text isEqualToString:self.retypePLabel.text]) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", @"Error") message:NSLocalizedString(@"Passwords do not match \n please retype", @"Passwords do not match \n please retype") delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    self.typePTextField.text = @"";
    self.retypePLabel.text = @"";
    return;
}
```

The alert appears even if I type the same string twice... and only the first text field geets reset to @"" ... 
What will fix this?

Comment: Have you verified that both `self.typePTextField` and `self.retypePLabel` are non-nil? Are you sure that 2nd one is correct? Shouldn't that be `self.retypePTextField`?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)  30 seconds in the debugger should tell you what's happening here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing in the isEqual: method

```
self.retypePLabel.text
```

should be

```
self.retypePTextField.text
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.retypePLabel.text`? are you sure you ask about this, because I think it should be like `self.retypePTextField.text`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 if (![self.typePTextField.text isEqualToString:self.sometextfield.text]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", @"Error") message:NSLocalizedString(@"Passwords do not match \n please retype", @"Passwords do not match \n please retype") delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        self.typePTextField.text = @"";
        self.sometextfield.text = @"";
        return;
    }
```

Comment: @ Fogmeister i know this is question is a year old but see the code what is this  self.retypePLabel.text ... i just correct the code ,, and why you voting me down

Comment: I down voted as the question has already been answered and accepted and the other answers are pretty much identical to the answer you gave.

Answer (score 0):

```
if([_txtPassword.text isEqual:_txtconfirmPassword.text])
    {
         NSLog(@"Password =%@   , ConfirmPassword = %@ ",_txtPassword.text,_txtconfirmPassword.text);
     }
     else {
        //// code show alert////
     }
```